# Vue computed property for showing the date

Tags: vue.js

I want the site to show todays date in the intro page. With vanilla JS is a breeze but with vue is way more harder, I can't make it work and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm using vue CLI here's the code:

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class ="date">
      Today is {{ date[0] }} of {{ date[1]}}
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
export default {
  data:function(){
    return{
      date:[]
    }
  },
  computed:{
    getTodaysDate(){
    var days=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

    var todaysDate = new Date();

    this.date[0] = days[todaysDate.getDay() -1];
    this.date[1] = months[todaysDate.getMonth() +1]

    return this.date
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retaining the array-based date and template from the question, it could be implemented something like this:

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    const todaysDate = new Date()
    const day = days[todaysDate.getDay()]
    const month = months[todaysDate.getMonth()]

    return {
      date: [day, month]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class ="date">
    Today is {{ date[0] }} of {{ date[1] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

There's no need for a computed property here, we can just populate the values in `data`.

Computed properties should not have side effects, so setting `this.date` inside a computed property would be considered incorrect usage. If you wanted to use a computed property you'd just return the relevant value and use it directly in the template.

It might look something like this:

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  computed: {
    date () {
      const todaysDate = new Date()
      const day = days[todaysDate.getDay()]
      const month = months[todaysDate.getMonth()]

      return [day, month]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class ="date">
    Today is {{ date[0] }} of {{ date[1] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

But as it isn't using any reactive data in the computation there really isn't any need to use a computed property for this.

Note I have also changed your array of days to start on Sunday so that it matches `getDay()`. I've also got rid of the `+1`/`-1` stuff as that would give the wrong values.

Comment: Ha! you made me break a sweat to figure it out but I finally did it, I used `mounted`  to execute a method that populated my data.

Comment: @ahzep The `mounted` hook is the wrong place to do it. That hook runs after rendering, so updating the data then requires two rounds of rendering. If you need a hook use `created`. Not really sure why you're using a hook at all rather than doing it in the `data` function like in my example.

Comment: Because it doesnt work with vue CLI, I just get an `Unexpected keyword 'const'`  error

Comment: @ahzep If you can't use `const` just use `var` instead. I use Vue CLI and `const` works fine. I suspect you may have mistyped something, perhaps writing `data: {` instead of `data () {`? I don't think it would say `Unexpected keyword` unless it recognised `const` as a keyword.